# how to display the special characters inside javascript function arguments

Tags: javascript, jsp

Below is the string that needs to be passed into the javascript function as i do not want to do the replace , i need to display the original subject string without any modification in the String value.

```
 String subject="The apostrophe ( ’ or ' ) < is a punctuation mark,";
 <td style="border: none"><a>href="javascript:showPopUpMsg('<%=subject%>')</a></td>
```

can you please suggest me how to parse these special characters.

Comment: You _have_ to escape the apostrophe (`'`), otherwise the jaavscript will have a syntax error

Comment: Escape it like this: `\'`

Comment: i get this String subject value dynamically with < ,',"",$,^characters . can you please tell me how accomodate for all

Answer (score 0):

Escape `'` character with backslash ():

```
String subject="The apostrophe ( ’ or \' ) < is a punctuation mark,";
 <td style="border: none"><a>href="javascript:showPopUpMsg('<%=subject%>')</a></td>
```

Also you can use String.replace ( see [String.replace method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm), for more info)

```
String subject="The apostrophe ( ’ or ' ) < is a punctuation mark,";
subject.replace("'", "\'");
```

href="javascript:showPopUpMsg('<%=subject%>')

Comment: thanks for the reply . This is very restrictive way, it needs be very generic like this escape( subject values for '). hope u are able to understand i cant change the value directly as i get that in my java bean something like String subject=test.getsubject()

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't write code to escape individual characters, but rather go with an existing library that already does the job - once and for all. You'll find information about the necessary escapes (*all* of them) as well as links to libraries on the [OWASP page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)