# pass string values into javascript function that contains special characters

Tags: javascript

HI can you please let me know how can i pass the below value to the javascript function argument:

i get this value dynamically from one of the java string variable like :

```
String vals= "The apostrophe ( ’ or ' ) is a punctuation < ! ^ & *mark,'";
```

that should gets parsed inside this function argumentshowPopUpMsgBanner

```
<html>
   <body>
 <button onclick="showPopUpMsgBanner('<%=vals%>')" >Click me</button>
 <script>
  function showPopUpMsgBanner(args){
 alert('values '+args);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only problem is single quote `'` you need to escape it using `\'` and don't use args.value only just args.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display the special characters inside javascript function arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793557/how-to-display-the-special-characters-inside-javascript-function-arguments)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions about identical code. If the answers to the original question were not answering the specific problem you were trying to solve, then edit that question to make it clearer what you are asking

Answer (score 3):

Just escape the innermost single quote `'`

```
 <button onclick="showPopUpMsgBanner('The apostrophe ( ’ or \' ) is a punctuation < ! ^ & *  mark,')" >Click me</button>
```

Also since you are directly passing the value, so no need to access its `value` property

```
 function showPopUpMsgBanner(args){
    alert('values '+args);
 }
```

Comment: @Sangeethacg are you using jsp or asp? You need to encode (or escape ' single quote) your string `vals` before it becomes part of a js string.